# Didn't understand relationship 'opportunity__c' in field path.

Tags: salesforce, soql

> Select id, Account.Type from opportunity__c

I create a custom object opportunity and make relational on Account__c and account data type lookup but above query does not run and give below error

> "Select id, Account.Type from opportunity__c
>              ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:12 Didn't understand relationship 'Account' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom
>   relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom
>   relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for
>   the appropriate names."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like account is a custom field, in which case the field is called account__c, and the relationship is called account__r so your query should be `select id, account__r.type from opportunity__c`

Comment: God bless you!!!! I spent some 40 minutes on this crap trying to do it as `SELECT Field, (SELECT MyField FROM Relationship__r) FROM Primary` and apparently that is not even a thing :face_palm:

Answer (score 1):

When you try to reach in a SOQL a field linked by a lookup or a Master-detail relationship you must put the suffix '__r' not the '__c'.

In your case, try with:

```
Select id, Account__r.Type from opportunity__c
```